# get image width and height without keeping it on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I **don't need** an image inside the DOM, but **need** to get it's dimensions.

Trying to create a temporary `img` element this way:

```
let src = 'images/01.jpg';
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = src;
let w = img.naturalWidth;
let h = img.naturalHeight;
console.log(w); // 0
console.log(h); // 0
$(img).remove();
```

Result is `0` and `0`. The real dimensions are `1349` and `250`.

How can I get them, without disturbing existing page layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to be loaded:

```js
let src = 'http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300';
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = () => {
  console.log(img.naturalWidth);
  console.log(img.naturalHeight);
}
img.src = src;
```

Until loaded, there's no way for the browser to know the dimensions of your image. If you need the dimensions in another function, you either have to use a *callback parameter* or *return a Promise*:

```js
let src = 'http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300';

// with a callback
const loadImgCallback = (url, callbackFn) => {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = () => { callbackFn(img); }
  img.src = src;
}

// with Promise
const loadImgPromise = url => new Promise((ok, fail) => {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = () => { ok(img); }
  img.onerror = fail;
  img.src = url;
});




/* === USAGE EXAMPLES === */
loadImgCallback(src, img => {
  console.log(`callback, naturalWidth: ${img.naturalWidth}`);
  console.log(`callback, naturalHeight: ${img.naturalHeight}`)
});

loadImgPromise(src).then(img => {
  console.log(`Promise, naturalWidth: ${img.naturalWidth}`);
  console.log(`Promise, naturalHeight: ${img.naturalHeight}`)
});
```

It's up to you to decide which solution you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it to the image object and for image to load :)

```js
let src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/428338/pexels-photo-428338.jpeg';
var img = new Image();
//img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = src;
img.onload = function() {
  let w = img.naturalWidth;
  let h = img.naturalHeight;
  console.log(w); // 0
  console.log(h); // 0
}

//$(img).remove();
```

Comment: very fine img, btw